# How to plot an HSV image with Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, hsv

I'am interested in finding a way to plot an HSV image in Matlab. I know i can do it by converting it into RGB first but I want to figure out whether there is a direct way. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe use  `colormap(hsv)`  after your call to `imshow` ? That's a wild guess haha

Comment: Define what you mean by "HSV" image.  Is your image already converted into HSV?  What are you specifically trying to plot?  This question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Ther is the `hsv2rgb` function to convert an hsv image to rgb, in case you were about to convert the values yourself.

Since monitors work with rgb the image has to be converted at some place before display, so i think it doesn't really matter when this takes place. I don't know of any more direct matlab approach than using hsv2rgb and then show the image and i do not think there is one. (of course you could put those two into a user defined script if that helps making code more readable).